# jaxb.properties file from java package not included in Maven built .war

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

I put a jaxb.properties file in the package where my classes are where I use a different JAXB provider (as seen in this link [Specifying EclipseLink MOXy as Your JAXB Provider](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html)) which I use for unmarshalling.

The following occurs:

- When I run the project from Eclipse/STS the unmarshalling works OK,
  since it reads the jaxb.properties file.
- When I build the project with Maven 3 (`mvn clean install`), the jaxb.properties file isn't included in the package - therefore those classes can't unmarshall XML files successfully. Then I have to manually put the jaxb.properties file by navigating to the deployed app, entering the package and pasting the file.

Solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should put resources(like jaxb.properties) in `src/main/resources`.
I can't find any proof/documentation yet, but I am certain that maven will only compile and copy `.java` files from the `src` folder.

From the documentation it seems clear, that compile will only compile and not copy anything. Therefore only .`java` files under src/main/java will be handled and everything else ignored.

Resources are handled by [resources:resources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/), which is executed automatically. This target copies resources from `src/main/resources`.

[Compile](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) only compiles files from the src folder. Resource files are not java files and will therefore not be copied/compiled to the output directory.

Comment: @HDave I believe he put the properties into src/main/resources

Comment: This is correct and explains the problem very well, but wont work - the jaxb.properties must go into /classes/path/to/model folder. Answer of Matthew Fellows is very helpful.

Comment: It works. One must map the package structure to the resources folder structure. Maven copies the properties to the correct path. No need to fiddle with its behaviour.

Answer (score 13):

As oers hinted, your best bet is to use the [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) to achieve this.

```xml
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/path/to/model/</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>jaxb.properties</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Place your `jaxb.properties` file in `directory` and specify the package location (`outputDirectory`) and this will copy the resource prior to packaging.

Comment: in my case the `<phase>validate</phase>` part was wrong, because the folder didn't exist at that phase I suppose. I changed it to `<phase>process-resources</phase>` and now it works

Answer (score 1):

add to your pom.xml

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/jaxb.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>         
    </resources>
```